# Deterministic asymmetric encryption

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, encryption-asymmetric, python-cryptography

Although it is not considered safe, I need a Python library that always generates for the same plaintext the same ciphertext using asymmetric encryption scheme.

Meaning that given a plaintext **m** and a public key **k** when encrypting **m** using **k** I will always get a constant ciphertext **c**.
It will be even better if there is a way to use the Python library "cryptography" to do so.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also I know it's not the `cryptography` library, but I've had success using [PyNaCl for secret key encryption](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/secret/).

Comment: Am I missing something, but isn't encryption by definition always (well, I'm sure there are exceptions) deterministic given a single plaintext and single public key?

Comment: @KenY-N No, it's never deterministic if it is IND-CPA secure, which is a stronger notion than just not encrypting to the same ciphertext when using the same plaintext message. That's why we have an IV for symmetric ciphers (which mixed with the key give you randomness) and random padding (or ephemeral keys etc.) for asymmetric ciphers.

Comment: @KenY-N No. That would be terrible. Say I provide you every day with an encrypted order -- either "yes, launch" or "no, don't launch". An attacker who intercepted just one message and saw whether or not you launched could decrypt all future messages. Ouchies! Humans shouldn't have to pad the plaintext with garbage to keep the system secure.

Comment: This is **NOT** a recommendation for the **VERY UNSECURE** mode of operation but there is a deterministic mode available for RSA encryption - it is called RSA with NoPadding" or "RSA textbook". Sorry for repeating and analogues to other answers/comment: using **this mode is VERY UNSECURE**. As far as I could find out it is available in the crypto-lib M2Crypto. ON 'https://github.com/mcepl/M2Crypto/blob/master/M2Crypto/RSA.py' I found the operating mode 'no_padding = m2.no_padding' that should fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can't find this because public-key encryption cannot possibly be deterministic. Any deterministic public-key encryption scheme is subject to a very simple attack: given a ciphertext, guess what the plaintext might be, and verify the guess by encrypting with the public key. Anyone can carry out this attack since the encryption key is public.

This is completely different from public-key signatures, which can be deterministic because being able to tell that two signatures are from the same message doesn't change anything about the signature's validity. With encryption, being able to tell that two plaintexts are the same message does break the whole purpose of encryption.

There is one scenario in which public-key encryption could be deterministic, and that's if the plaintexts are randomly generated, or derived from randomly generated data, and it's impossible to guess potential plaintexts. However, with such input restrictions, you shouldn't look for an “asymmetric encryption” scheme, but for a lower-level primitive: a trapdoor permutation. This is not a directly usable primitive, but it can be a building block of a cryptographic mechanism (such as a public-key encryption mechanism). So you can't expect libraries to offer that as their interface. Furthermore, typical protocols are not generic in the way they might use a trapdoor permutation. So your protocol definition would call for a specific primitive, not for a “deterministic asymmetric encryption” primitive.

If you think you need “deterministic asymmetric encryption”, you're designing your own cryptographic scheme, and it does not stand a chance of being correct. Don't do that. If you need help solving a problem, [ask about your actual problem instead of the dead end you've reached trying to solve it](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Thanks I Actually need it for randomly generated data